# Dimmer is controlling outlets

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch

I have a walk-in closet that was wired with one hot lead from the bathroom. I want to put in a dimmer for the lights but there are also 2 outlets coming off of the hot. When I put the hot wire together with the black wires from the dimmer and the outlets the dimmer controls the outlets as well as the lights. Is there any way to make it so the outlets are on a constant flow and the dimmer only controls the lights?

Comment: When was this wired in?  Also, is there a light switch there *now*?  Does the light switch switch the receptacles also?

Comment: Also, do you *really need* the ability to set the lights to varying levels of brightness, or do you just want it dimmer than it is now? Are these LED or CFL lights, or old incandescent?

Comment: Can you send pic of box with dimmer wires? And the oulets  to. Did they always work by a switch ?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Answer (score 2):

It would be a code violation to have a outlet connected to a dimmer, I would want to figure out where the hot is at the dimmer and connect the outlets to that then run the dimmer only to the light and that would be code compliant.